# Do not show on homepage functions.php code needed

Tags: functions

I'm using a plugin called [Float Left Right Advertising](http://wordpress.org/plugins/float-left-right-advertising/) however I don't want to work on the homepage.

I tried adding this code into the functions.php but it doesn't work:

```
add_action( 'float_left_right_advertising' ); 

function float_left_right_advertising() { 
  if ( is_home() ) { 
    wp_deregister_script( 'float-left-right-advertising' );
  }
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you try using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page function instead of is_home() ?

Comment: Thank you for some reason this code didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your code should work. You have to `add_action` to some hook (this function takes at least 2 params and you only use one of them).

```
add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

Also there is no script called `float-left-right-advertising` registered by this plugin.

Something like this, on the other hand, will work:

```
function disable_flradv() {
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
        remove_action('wp_footer', 'append_code_to_body');
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'disable_flradv');
```

PS. You also have to be careful, if you want to use `is_home` (and so on) functions. You shouldn't use them before `wp_query` object is initialized.

Comment: I did try all suggestions and the one by Krysiek Drozdz worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpse_104961_float_left_right_advertising' );

function wpse_104961_float_left_right_advertising() {
  if ( wp_script_is( 'float-left-right-advertising' ) {
    if ( is_home( ) || is_front_page( ) ) {
      wp_deregister_script( 'float-left-right-advertising' );
    }
  }
}
```

> [wp_print_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_scripts)
>   Runs just before WordPress prints registered JavaScript scripts into the page header.
>
> [wp_script_is](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php#L136)
>   Determine if a script has been registered, queued, printed, or is waiting to be printed.

Comment: It won't help. This plugin doesn't register script with given name. Second reason it won't work is that this plugin outputs html and js code with some action hooked to `wp_footer`.

Comment: Why would OP deregister `float-left-right-advertising` then? Ah never mind, maybe it'll give OP more insights of using actions and conditional WordPress logic.

Comment: I have no idea why :)